# 'Chart' object has no attribute 'configure_facet_cell'

Tags: python, bar-chart, configure, facet, altair

I am using Altair package when I use following objects I have following error message.

AttributeError: 'Chart' object has no attribute 'configure_facet_cell'

In order to use attribute above, what should I install or add?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `configure_facet_cell` was a method available in early versions of Altair that has been deprecated and removed, with its functionality mainly replaced by ``configure_view``. If you edit your question to include the code you tried to execute, someone may be able to help you translate it to the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments this was created on an early version of the software and is no longer reproducible on current Altair versions.